# Is it possible to run node workers inside express application

Tags: node.js, express, worker

I am trying to implement node workers inside node/express application and getting bellow error(server listening on port 3002)

```
{"level":"error","message":{"code":"EADDRINUSE","errno":-98,"syscall":"listen","address":"::","port":3002},"service":"server"}
```

is it possible to have a separate port for node workers?  or I am trying to implement antipattern?

app.js

```
const app = express()
...
app.use("/api/search", accommodation)
...
app.set('port', 3002);
```

accommodation controller

```
(req, res, next) => {


        if (isMainThread) {
            const workers = []


            const callback = (data) => {
                console.log(data)

                workers[0].removeListener("message", callback)
                workers[1].removeListener("message", callback)
                workers[0].unref()
                workers[1].unref()
            }

            const createWorker = (id, index) => {
                const worker = new Worker(__filename, { workerData: { id, index }})
                worker.on("error", err => { throw err })
                worker.on("message", callback)
                return worker
            }
            workers[0] = createWorker("id0", 0)
            workers[1] = createWorker("id1", 1)
        }
        else {
            console.log('this is worker')

            parentPort.postMessage({ msg: "worker started" })
            parentPort.on("message", (msg) => {
                console.log(msgs)
                if (msg === "terminate") {
                    exit(1)
                }
                if (msg === "next") {
                    parentPort.postMessage({ msg: {}})
                }
                exit(1)
            })
        }

        res.send("ok")
    }
```

Comment: You don't show the relevant code, but if the worker is trying to also set up a server, you can't use the same port in different workers as that results in `EADDRINUSE`, you would have to use separate ports for each worker.  We could help better if you backed up a few steps and explained what you're trying to accomplish with the workers in the first place and showed relevant code.

Comment: yes, it seems both app port and worker try to listen same port, now I have updated the question with parts of my code.

Comment: Are you trying to cluster your server?  If so, use the cluster module.  It handles this port issue and load balancing for you.  If not, you'll have to explain what you're trying to do because right now, you're trying to load the exact same file that your main app is in multiple workers.  That is not usually how you use workers and probably explains why every worker is trying to start the same express server on the same port which you cannot do.